# C++ (Virtual) Function Table

Tags: c++, oop

Is the C++ vtable only used for determining which section of code should be executed when a call is made to a virtual function, or does it have other uses at run-time?

On wikipedia it lists "dynamic dispatch" as a reason, but doesn't go into further details for C++.....

Comment: I guess it can also be used to describe the offsets of virtual base class subobjects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some implementations place a pointer to information used by RTTI code (`typeid`, `dynamic_cast`, ...) in a slot of the vtable (see here about the [Itanium ABI](http://sourcery.mentor.com/public/cxx-abi/abi.html#vtable), on which the g++ ABI is based).

<sub>(actually, if you read the Itanium ABI specification it's slightly more convoluted, but this is the general idea)</sub>

Also, as you can see from the linked document, there's some more stuff to access the data of the base class, perform pointer adjustment when calling base-class methods, ..., mostly stuff needed in "complicated" object hierarchies (multiple inheritance, virtual base classes, ...), as in the classic single inheritance scenario the layout of a derived class is straightforward and doesn't require all this fuss.

Comment: Would you say the table only lists virtual functions and no other types of function?

Comment: Why would it need to list non-virtual functions?

Comment: Well some dynamic dispatch events could be non-virtual? (Thats a question rather than statement)

Comment: @user997112: dynamic dispatch works *by definition* only with virtual functions. Otherwise what would be the point of marking them as `virtual`? Non-virtual function calls are resolved at compile-time with the static type known by the compiler.

Comment: @user997112, non-virtual functions are fully identified at compile time so there's no need to redirect through a table.

Comment: @Matteo, coming from a Java background I can have two classes implementing an Interface and use the Interface as the parameter type. At run-time dynamic dispatch works out which class has been passed into the function call and calculates which code to call. I wasn't sure if C++ has this too. So you're saying the only run-time unknown (besides RTTI) in C++ is virtual functions?

Comment: @user997112: in Java all functions are virtual by default, in C++ you have to explicitly ask for this behavior marking the functions that need dynamic dispatch with `virtual` (the background idea in C++ is that you shouldn't pay for what you don't need, so, if you don't need dynamic dispatch, you don't mark the functions as `virtual`, allowing the compiler to optimize more aggressively). And yes, in standard C++ the only dynamic part of the type system is the virtual dispatch and RTTI (which includes the information needed for pointer adjustment, ... in `dynamic_cast`).

Comment: Just to be extra clear: there's nothing like Java reflection in C++.

Comment: Thanks Matteo! I never realised all Java functions are virtual! I had always assumed the 'virtual function' was just linked to Java abstract/non-abstract methods.... with a pure virtual being a Java abstract method.

Comment: pure virtual => abstract; virtual => "normal" Java function; non-virtual => no equivalent in Java.

Comment: @user997112: I _expect_ the vtable to contain only virtual methods, but the C++ standard definitely allows the vtable to contain all methods. A compiler which implements reflections (as an extension to C++) would likely do so.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ vtable is simply a lookup table for function pointers.  Any specific C++ implementation may use the vtable for other things; but that is implementation (and version) specific.  Relying on the vtable for anything other than C++ to invoke your virtual methods is a really bad idea.

Comment: Actually, the C++ standard doesn't even mention the vtable or any possible implementation of virtual function and other stuff, so you shouldn't rely even on the very *existence* of vtable.